# Flushing issue with JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In spring boot while using JPA. What I am doing IN the sequence explained below.

```
--- Some Data ----- (Step 1)
entityName.saveAndFlush(); // I can see data in table

-- Some Data --- (Step 2)
entityName.saveAll(); // I can see data in table

-- Now ---- (Step 3)
OtherEntity.runNativeQuery(); // Again first query of Step 1 gets executed which replaces the data of step 2
```

Here the problem is why data of step 2 is replaced by step 1 while doing step 3

I tried deattaching the entity after step 1. It was no help.

DB - PSQL with PGADMIN

```
 private void persistGeoObjectsPerArea(final GenericArea area){
                GenericArea basicArea = area.toBasic();
                areaRepository.saveAndFlush(basicArea);
 }

 private void persistAllVirtualGeoObjectsPerArea(final GenericArea area, final GenericFloor floorIdentity,
            final Principal principal) {
   // Some code to update area

  // Save all the areas from payload
        areaRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(area));
}

private void saveGeoHierarchyData(final List<GenericClient> clients) {
    persistGeoObjectsPerArea();

    persistAllVirtualGeoObjectsPerArea();
            networkInterfaceRepository.insertIdentityNativeQuery(networkInt.getId(), networkInt.getName());

}
```

Comment: What do you mean you can see data in table? How do you check that?

Comment: While debugging. I hold on to the point where the execution of step 1 gets completed and see in DB.

Comment: What database are you using and how are you looking at the databse?

Comment: Using PSQL. Using query on PGADMIN I am.

Comment: And these steps are running in the same transaction?

Comment: yes, it does run in same transaction

Comment: But then you shouldn't see it in the database!

Comment: I am not sure about transactions but we are using JPARepository so manually we are not handling any transactions and commit while save or saveAll on the method level. Hence assuming it to be one transaction by default

Comment: Can you please show your code

Comment: Added code in question

Comment: And from where is this code called? Where is the transactional annotation?

Comment: @Transactional annotation not used. As I said in the last comment.

Comment: But then I don't understand your question. Sorry.

Comment: I have not user @Transaction annot. I am asking that without annotation calling a saveGeoHierarchyData then in step 3 the data of step 2 is replaced by step 1 on execution of step 3

Comment: What is insertIdentityNativeQuery?

Comment: It's a function in the Repository class
(at)Modifying
(at)Transactional
 (at)Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES (:id, :name)")
    int insertIdentityNativeQuery(@NotEmpty @Param("id") final UUID id, Param("name") final String name);

Comment: And this will overwrite the changes. What did you expect will happen?

Comment: Let me rephrase it again. In Step 1 and Step 2 the entity is the same which is Generic Area. But in step 1 basic entity (to avoid fk expectation) is saved then later in step 2 some more data added to the same entity and saved again. In step 3 some other entity data is inserted with the native query. So while step 3 gets executed the data of step 2 which was in DB gets replaceed by step 1 data. Coz, the queries of step 1 get executed on the execution of step 3.